# I set HTTP_PROXY in CMD, but IDLE not recognizing it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to install Beautifulsoup4, and was having trouble with my connection.  I set my HTTPS_PROXY variable, and then I downloaded Beautifulsoup4 without issue.

Now, I am writing some beautifulsoup4 scripts in INDLE and Running the Module, and I am finding that Python is again having trouble connecting to the internet.  I am getting the connection refusal error.

How do I set the HTTPS_PROXY variable so that I can connect to the internet when I am running a script written in Idle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you set *HTTPS_PROXY* environment variable in terminal session, it affects only that session and is reset when you close that session.

You can set environment variables **system-wide** (which will take effect on every program and system itself, so be careful) by adding it to your environment or **modify the environment directly** from your Python script which will only affect your script (this is the behaviour you are probably want). Note that the value of *HTTPS_PROXY* in that case will be reset when the script terminates:

```
import os
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "*your_proxy_parameters*"
```

You can read more about working with environment variables in Python's official documentation for **os** module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).

For modifying your system-wide environment please refer to your OS's documentation.